# simple question about simple polynomial... $(y \sqrt{3} + 1)(2+4y \sqrt{3})$

Tags: polynomials

Please, could someone show how to count that polynomial with all the phases? $(y \sqrt{3} + 1)(2+4y\sqrt{3})$. I know it's a simple thing but need some help on it.

Comment: What do you mean by "to count the polynomial with all the phases"? This is a polynomial, what do you have to do with it?

Comment: I'm trying to reduce it to 12y^2 + 6√3y + 2. I'm getting different result when I'm doing it.

Comment: It would then be great if you type what you have been doing so that one could comment on your work.

Comment: $$(y \sqrt{3}+1)(2+4y \sqrt{3})= y \sqrt{3}\cdot 2 + y \sqrt{3}\cdot 4y \sqrt{3} + 1\cdot 2 + 1 \cdot 4y \sqrt{3}= \\
=2 \sqrt{3}y + 12y^2 + 2 + 4 \sqrt{3}y = 12y^2 + 6 \sqrt{3}y +2$$ do you find this difficult?

Answer (score 0):

To do this really slowly:  First distribute one factor over the other:

$$(y\sqrt{3}+1)(2+4y\sqrt{3}) = y\sqrt{3}(2+4y\sqrt{3})+1(2+4y\sqrt{3}).$$

Then distribute the other factor:

$$= (y\sqrt{3})2+(y\sqrt{3})(4y\sqrt{3}) + 1(2) + 1(4y\sqrt{3}).$$

Now re-arrange a bit:

$$= 4\sqrt{3}\sqrt{3}y^2 + 2y\sqrt{3}+4y\sqrt{3} + 2.$$

Note that $\sqrt{3}{\sqrt{3} = 3 and that you can add the middle terms together:

$$=4\cdot 3 y^2 + (2+4)y\sqrt{3} + 2.$$

Then $3\cdot 4 = 12$ and $2+4=6$, so:

$$=12y^2+6y\sqrt{3}+2,$$

as desired.